# What is the correct way of polymorphism for plain data objects?

Tags: c++, coding-style, polymorphism

I have an **Item** class that represents an item which can be drawn on the screen. Let's say that the item can be a piece of text, an image or a solid color rect.
I also have a class that contains a collection of such items.

I can imagine two different approaches to implement these classes. I have a **Drawer** class to draw these items with an interface like this:

```
Draw(Item& item);
```

The first approach:

```
class Item
{
    Point Position;
}

class Text : public Item
{
    string Text;
}

class Image : public Item
{
    string FilePath;
}

class Rect : public Item
{
    Color FillColor;
}

class ItemCollection
{
    vector<Item*> Items;
}
```

The first approach uses **inheritance** to differentiate between the different types of items. The downside to this solution is that I have to use some kind of **handle** (a simple pointer in the above example) when storing the items in a vector to create a heterogeneous collection, and that the Item& reference has to be **casted** to its concrete type in the Draw function.

The second approach:

```
class Item
{
    ItemType Type;

    Point Position;
    string Text;
    string FilePath;
    Color FillColor;
};

enum class ItemType { Text, Image, Rect };

class ItemCollection
{
    vector<Item> Items;
}
```

In this solution a **single class** contains all the data members of the different items. The benefit is that now the vector in the collection class can contain real Item **values**, and that **no casting** will be needed in the Draw function.
However, the drawback is that the memory usage of the Item class is not optimal, because every kind of item instance will contain a number of fields that it does not really need. Also, if later additional item types get added, then the Item class will get cluttered with all their new fields.

(I know that a third possible approach would be to put an abstract virtual Draw method in the base Item class, but I can not do that because in my situation these classes can only contain data, and no logic.)

Which is usually the preferred solution in a situation like this?

Comment: You could have a `union` of pointers to `Point`, `string`, `Color`. And `Type` would tell you which one to use.

Comment: WTB either `struct` or some `public:` s.

Comment: *(I know that a third possible approach would be to put an abstract virtual Draw method in the base Item class, but I can not do that because in my situation these classes can only contain data, and no logic.)* Two questions on that: **1:** Is there any *good* reason why they can only contain data? **2:** Does a pointer to another object count as *data*, if that other object contains logic? (thinking of a polymorphic pimpl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Visitor Pattern

> I know that a third possible approach would be to put an abstract virtual Draw method in the base Item class, but I can not do that because in my situation these classes can only contain data, and no logic.

Try [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) - all your logic will be in visitor classes not objects. Each object would have only one **virtual** method - **accept(Visitor&)**.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c7ab18d1d9ddd9d)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

using Color = int;

struct Text;
struct Image;
struct Rect;

struct Visitor
{
    virtual void operator()(const Text &x) const=0;
    virtual void operator()(const Image &x) const=0;
    virtual void operator()(const Rect &x) const=0;
};

struct IVisitable
{
    virtual void accept(Visitor&)=0;
    virtual ~IVisitable(){}
};
template<typename Derived>
struct Visitable : IVisitable
{
    void accept(Visitor &v) override
    {
        v(*static_cast<Derived*>(this));
    }
};

struct Text: Visitable<Text>
{
    string Text = "text";
};

struct Image: Visitable<Image>
{
    string FilePath = "path";
};

struct Rect: Visitable<Rect>
{
    Color FillColor = 11;
};

struct Draw: Visitor
{
    void operator()(const Text &x) const override
    {
        cout << "Text: " << x.Text << endl;
    }
    void operator()(const Image &x) const override
    {
        cout << "image: " << x.FilePath << endl;
    }
    void operator()(const Rect &x) const override
    {
        cout << "Rect: " << x.FillColor << endl;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<IVisitable>> items;
    items.emplace_back(new Text);
    items.emplace_back(new Image);
    items.emplace_back(new Rect);
    Draw v;
    for(auto &&x: items)
        x->accept(v);
}
```

Output is:

```
Text: text
image: path
Rect: 11
```

---

## Boost.Variant

> However, the drawback is that the memory usage of the Item class is not optimal, because every kind of item instance will contain a number of fields that it does not really need. Also, if later additional item types get added, then the Item class will get cluttered with all their new fields.

Consider [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) as optimization of that technique. Your variant will have size of **max item**, not accumulation of all fields:

```
std::vector<boost::variant<Text, Image, Rect>> items;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c07b28a0e53bddd3)

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

using Color = int;

struct Text
{
    string Text;
};

struct Image
{
    string FilePath;
};

struct Rect
{
    Color FillColor;
};

struct Draw : static_visitor<void>
{
    void operator()(const Text &x) const
    {
        cout << "Text: " << x.Text << endl;
    }
    void operator()(const Image &x) const
    {
        cout << "image: " << x.FilePath << endl;
    }
    void operator()(const Rect &x) const
    {
        cout << "Rect: " << x.FillColor << endl;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    vector<variant<Text, Image, Rect>> items = 
    {
        Text{"text"},
        Image{"path"},
        Rect{55}
    };
    Draw v;
    for_each(items,apply_visitor(v));
}
```

Output is:

```
Text: text
image: path
Rect: 55
```

Comment: The virtual accept method would clearly be logic, violating his "data only" constraints.

Comment: "only contain data, and no logic" - **accept** is not really logic, it is just helper function. Real logic would be defined outside. Morever, non-intusive visition approaches [do exist](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813#), without **accept** method.

Answer (score 1):

> (I know that a third possible approach would be to put an abstract virtual Draw method in the base Item class, but I can not do that because in my situation these classes can only contain data, and no logic.)

This is the correct approach if you are looking for polymorphism, as the question title states. Consider revising your program if it is unacceptable to you.
The other two approaches you mentioned both rely on having an `ItemType` variable, which is exactly what polymorphism is meant to avoid.

> Also, if later additional item types get added, then the Item class will get cluttered with all their new fields.

This is also solved by polymorphism, as the Drawer implementation does not need to know about new object types.

If you are intent on keeping it simple, the first example is okay, but you need a `type` variable so you can tell which kind of object you're dealing with.